# IntelliJ: How to highlight the negation operator (!) differently than the text?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a very particular aversion to the `!` operator after spending many hours hunting bugs caused by missing it, so I would like IntelliJ to highlight it in some way.

I've tried coloring Operators under `Editor ⟶ Color Scheme ⟶ Defaults ⟶ Operation sign`, but it doesn't color `!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **Operator sign** under the Settings(Preferences) | Editor | Color Scheme | Java settings.

Invoke **Jump To Colors and Fonts** action (Ctrl/Cmd+Shift+A shortcut):
[image]

to navigate to the relevant to the current cursor position color options:
[image]

Comment: It works in Java, but I guess it just does't work in the Scala plugin for some reason :\